# Opening Neo4j database from .NET code

Tags: vb.net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am running Neo4j locally and VB.NET coded software. Right now I have to open the database with Neo4j community in advance of running the software.  I'd like to be able to open the database from within the .NET code, like I can with other databases (MS SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, etc.).  I cannot find any documentation on how to do this with Neo4j.  Of course, I'd also like to check its status and close it from code too.

Appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks.

Dave

Comment: Try looking here: http://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/

Comment: I have referenced Neo4jClient and used the code at https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/connecting.  But this does not connect; specific database to be opened is not identified.  I could not locate such functionality in Neo4jClient.  What am I missing here?

Comment: When you say it doesn't connect what do you mean? Does it throw an exception when you do a `client.Connect()`? By specific database to be opened, are you meaning something like `Server=Localhost;Database=Test1`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm being imprecise.  I am trying to START the server from code.  The code I'm using opens a database when the server has been started.  You can start SQL Server from .NET code; can you do this with Neo4j?

Comment: David, I would offer that letting the operating system start/stop services is probably the best practice. I believe your code should simply catch the exception if it cannot connect to the database, log the exception and exit gracefully.

Comment: The simple answer is no, the .Net client only connects via the REST end point for Neo4j, so the server has to be running. The only way I can think of is using the Java API instead of .NET, but let's face it, that's not really an option.

Comment: There is also a great introduction video tutorial on using Neo4j from .Net: https://wintellectnow.com/Videos/Watch?videoId=getting-started-with-graph-databases-using-neo4j

Comment: Thanks to all.  I'll have the server running and not use code to start it.